# Get all videos in a library to embed in page using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript

I have a video library in SharePoint 2013 and want to embed those videos in a publishing page on another site collection using JavaScript. The videos should be in a special order defined by a column "order".
What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript to get the videos and video.js to display them on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The various way we can display the video in the SharePoint 2013 page - below are some recommended ways:

**Media Web Part**

This Web Part has been around since SharePoint 2010. Simply add it to a page, then use the Media tab at the top to configure its properties, such as the video to look at and whether to play it automatically. This Web Part has been around since SharePoint 2010. Simply add it to a page, then use the Media tab at the top to configure its properties, such as the video to look at and whether to play it automatically.

**Video as page content**

Also, on publishing pages and wiki pages, media content can directly be inserted into content areas, and the configuration of the media itself is the same. When editing these types of pages, the Insert tab will contain an option for video. You can navigate to your SharePoint content, or use the embed code for any video from SharePoint or the Internet.

**Content Search Web Part**

This is a new Web Part in SharePoint 2013, along with a whole category of Web Parts called Search-Driven Content. Video content can be displayed in this Web Part, and there is a Web-Part setting called Control, which has a setting called Slideshow. Videos can be displayed in this slideshow style so that they can be scrolled through in a pretty graphical interface. This screenshot is of a Content Search Web Part on the home page, which shows one video at a time and has two total videos:

Reference URL:

[WORKING WITH VIDEO CONTENT IN SHAREPOINT 2013](https://wonderlaura.com/2015/01/07/working-with-video-content-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**Notes**:

- If you want more control over the displaying the video in a page, then the **Content Search Web Part** is recommended - this web part had been introduced in the SharePoint 2013 where we can customize the **item display template and header display template**, in this approach everything is under the control of developer because it is completely code based (javascript coding from the search result).